# Why importing is giving an error Module not found: Can't resolve?

Tags: reactjs, mobx-react

I have two `react` projects. One with just components. And another with pages that import the components and a corresponding store. And I am using `mobx`.

In the component project I have an ts file with the name , `ISoftwareProps.ts` that has an interface and a class.

```
    export interface ISoftwareProps {
        software: Software[];
    }
    export default class Software {
        id: number;
        name: string;
        @observable status: string;
        @observable ipAddress: string;

        constructor(obj: Software) {
            this.id = obj.id;
            this.name = obj.name;
            this.status = obj.status;
            this.ipAddress = obj.ipAddress;
        }
    }
```

In my second project, I am trying to import the software class. This gives the following error.

> Module not found: Can't resolve '@caas/gatewaymanagercomponent/lib/component/Software/ISoftwareProps'

If i try to import the interface `ISoftwareProps`, it works fine.

1. Tried renaming the Software class as the same as ts file name

The error shouldn't appear.

Comment: Add your import statement here

Comment: import Software from '@gatewaymanagercomponent/lib/component/Software/ISoftwareProps';

Comment: add the working import too

Comment: import ISoftwareProps from '../../../models/Software/ISoftwareProps';